# Count friends of my friend in facebook using Facebook C# SDK

Tags: c#-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk

Is there anyway to just see how many friends that friend has? 
Example: My Friends - Sylvain (has 300 friends) - Olivier (has 145 friends)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This FQL query](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20friend_count,%20uid%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20IN%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20=%20me%28%29%29%0A) will get the `friend_count` field for all the loggedin user's friends.

```
SELECT friend_count, uid FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```